# 3 classes em java, uma chamando a outra, como chamar metodos da primeira pra última? (bluej)

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho 3 classes,  sao elas:  locacao, carros, e cliente. Locacao contém carros, e cliente contem locacao. Se eu quero, na classe cliente, chamar um dos métodos da classe carro, como faço? 
Por exemplo, um objeto cliente contem um vetor de locações, e cada uma dessas locações tem um carro. Eu quero, por exemplo, o retorno ta placa do carro, na classe cliente.

Comment: Ja possui algum código? Ou nem que seja o diagrama de classe? Herança não te ajudaria? OU ate mesmo uma interface básica

Comment: Eu to tentando fazer a um tempo, mas como o codigo depende dessa parte pra eu prosseguir, não tive como escrever mais, infelizmente.

Comment: Não é meu forte, mas acredito que vc terá que usar algum padrão de projeto( Desin patters - Gof) para resolver, pois para retonar a placa do carro na classe cliente me parece muito semelhante ao padrão comportamental Iterator, dê uma procura nele e veja se as coisas ficarão mais claras ai

Answer (score 1):

Classes podem ser usadas para declarar variáveis dentro de outras classes.

EX:

```
public class A {
  private String nome;

  public A(String nome){
    this.nome = nome;
  }

  public String getNome() { return this.nome; }
}
```

Em outra classe

```
public class B {
  private A a;

  public B() {
    a = new A("Test");
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println(a.getNome());
  }
}
```

Como você não colocou o código das suas classes eu criei aqui umas classes bem simples para facilitar a explicação.

As explicações estão comentadas no próprio código, se tiver alguma duvida depois é só perguntar.

Carro.java

```java
public class Carro {
    private String marca, ano;

    // Cria um carro com sua marca e ano.
    public Carro(String marca, String ano) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    // Métodos acessores

    public String getMarca() { return marca; }

    public void setMarca(String marca) { this.marca = marca; }

    public String getAno() { return ano; }

    public void setAno(String ano) { this.ano = ano; }
}
```

Locacao.java

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Locacao {
    // Lista de carros.
    private List<Carro> carros;

    // Cria uma locacao com uma lista de carros vazia.
    public Locacao() {
        this.carros = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // Métodos acessores

    public List<Carro> getCarros() { return carros; }

    public void setCarros(List<Carro> carros) { this.carros = carros; }
}
```

Cliente.java

```
public class Cliente {
    private String nome;
    private Locacao locacao;

    // Cria um cliente com seu nome e locacao.
    public Cliente(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.locacao = new Locacao();
    }

    // Métodos acessores

    public String getNome() { return nome; }

    public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

    public Locacao getLocacao() { return locacao; }

    public void setLocacao(Locacao locacao) { this.locacao = locacao; }
}
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Cria um cliente.
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente("José");

        // Cria três carros.
        Carro carro1 = new Carro("Fiat", "2015");
        Carro carro2 = new Carro("Hyundai", "2017");
        Carro carro3 = new Carro("Jeep", "2019");

        // Pega a lista de carros que pertence a classe Locacao que pertence a classe Cliente.
        List<Carro> carros = cliente.getLocacao().getCarros();

        // Adiciona os três carros a lista.
        carros.add(carro1);
        carros.add(carro2);
        carros.add(carro3);

        System.out.printf("A locação do cliente %s possui %d carros.\n", cliente.getNome(), carros.size());

        // Faz um loop na lista de carros, mostrando cada carro com sua marca e ano.
        for(Carro carro: carros){
            System.out.printf("Carro(marca=%s, ano=%s)\n", carro.getMarca(), carro.getAno());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como funciona no bluej, mas no netbeans e outros é só instanciar a classe

```
Carros carro = new Carros();

Object placa = carro.metodoPegaPlaca(idCarro);
```

Isso ai vc colocaria na classe cliente

Espero que eu tenha te ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Como você não colocou o código, fiz um do zero, dá uma olhada pra ver se tira a duvida, não usei métodos acessores tentando deixar o mais claro possível.

---

Declarando Variáveis

```
public class Carros{
       String placa;

}

public class Locacao{
       String marcaDocarro;

}

public class Cliente{
       String nome;

}
```

Declarando valores

```
Carros novoCarro = new Carros;

novoCarro.placa = "AAA-1111";
```

---

```
Locacao novaLocacao = new Locacao;

novaLocacao.marcaDocarro = "FORD";
```

---

```
Cliente novoCliente = new Cliente;

novoCliente.nome = "joão";
```

---

Atribuindo chamadas nas classes

```
public class Locacao{

       String marcaDocarro;

//chamando o Objeto Carros

Carros novoCarroLocado;

}

public class Cliente{

       String nome;

//chamando o Objeto Locacao

Locacao novoCarroLocado;

}
```

Declarando a chamada na classe principal

```
Carros novoCarro = new Carros;

novoCarro.placa = "AAA-1111";

novaLocacao.novoCarroLocado(novoCarro );
```

---

```
Locacao novaLocacao = new Locacao;

novaLocacao.marcaDocarro = "FORD";

novoCliente.novoCarroLocado(novaLocacao );
```

---

Chamando os dados

```
System.out.println(novaLocacao.novoCarroLocado(novoCarro.placa);

System.out.println(novoCliente.novoCarroLocado(novaLocacao.marcaDocarro );
```